# How can I transfer one Stata dataset's variable labels (not value labels) to another dataset's variables?

Tags: dataset, label, stata

I have one data set with all variables labeled and another one not at all. The two datasets have the same set of variables. How can I use the first dataset's variable labels (not value labels) in the other data set?

Answer (score 1):

If you type this loop while the dataset with variable labels is in memory

```
foreach v of var * {
    di `" label var `v' "`: var label `v''" "'
}
```

you will get a series of commands to copy and paste into a do-file to apply to the other dataset. There's almost certainly a program to do this, but `search label` came up with too many finds for me to want to read through to find a program rather than write one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach that may work; beware though if the variables in the two files are not of the same type.

```
. use `file2', clear

. describe

Contains data from /var/folders/xr/lm5ccr996k7dspxs35yqzyt80000gp/T//S_00996.000009
  obs:             5                          
 vars:             1                          8 Jun 2016 21:21
 size:            20                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x               float   %9.0g                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: 

. use `file1', clear

. describe

Contains data from /var/folders/xr/lm5ccr996k7dspxs35yqzyt80000gp/T//S_00996.000007
  obs:             5                          
 vars:             1                          8 Jun 2016 21:22
 size:            20                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x               float   %9.0g                 this is a label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: 

. drop in 1/L
(5 observations deleted)

. append using `file2'

. describe

Contains data from /var/folders/xr/lm5ccr996k7dspxs35yqzyt80000gp/T//S_00996.000007
  obs:             5                          
 vars:             1                          8 Jun 2016 21:22
 size:            20                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x               float   %9.0g                 this is a label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: 
     Note: Dataset has changed since last saved.

.
```